# Muzzle or not? What would you call this thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, animals

What would you call this in English?

[image]

What's this white thing on cat's or rabbit's muzzle? Or is this a muzzle itself? Would it be right to say, "This is a head with a white muzzle?"

Comment: You should be aware that starting every word with a capital letter, like you have done, is a **gross error** in written English.

Comment: Are you wanting to know what it is called on this toy or on a real animal?

Comment: Is the picture of something that is **covering up** the animal's nose and mouth? If not, are you asking for one of several possible synonyms for *nose*? (Because the arrows that were drawn do not point to the pink nose—they all point to the blank space where a *mouth* would normally be.)

Answer (score 7):

It's a ***SNOUT***.

According to [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snout) :

**snout**

*NOUN*

The projecting nose and mouth of an animal, especially a mammal.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snout?wprov=sfla1) :

"In many animals, the equivalent structure is called a muzzle, rostrum, or proboscis."

Here's  an [example](http://www.mibepa.info/tb/tb004c.htm) :

"You can choose between many different snouts. A large or precise a small snout. A hairy or a shaved snout. A similar color snout or contrast color."

(The anatomy of a teddy bear)

Comment: That's a *nose*. Snouts are elongated, and muzzles include both a nose and a mouth See *Merriam Webster*: [**muzzle**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muzzle):  the projecting jaws and nose of an animal; [**snout**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snout) a long projecting nose (as of a swine). (But since rabbits are said to have snouts and muzzles, you could easily call it one.)

Comment: It depends - does the "white area" include the mouth? I cannot tell from the image.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine places where this cat's mouth could be that *aren't* within the white area, and none of them seem terribly plausible to me. A cat's mouth is normally right under its nose, which would place it right in the middle of the white area on this photo.

Comment: @AdmiralJota That’s a cat?!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The original question asks "What's this white thing on cat's or rabbit's muzzle?", and those ears seem to be shaped more like a cat's than a rabbit's.

Comment: The Wikipedia definition you provide also includes *muzzle, rostrum, or proboscis*. So, are you saying *that* definition is wrong and it's *not* a *muzzle*? Or are you making some kind of subjective statement about which is the better synonym? (I would think that *nose* would be far more common than *snout*.)

Comment: @Peter I think it would have been much better if you submitted your comment as an answer rather than a comment. Now I can't up upvote it as the most correct answer.